# Converting a string to LongInt in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to convert a string to LongInt type. How to do that?

Should I use `to_i` method only? Or there is any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no longint type. Integers in ruby can hold arbitrarily large values. So yeah, just use `.to_i`.